# sql query: which students have repeated subject?

Tags: mysql, sql

table structure is like :

```
student area yearlevel code year sem result
123010  INFO         9 0002 2015   1     77
123011  INFO         9 0002 2015   1     70
123012  INFO         9 0002 2015   1     55
123037  INFO         9 0002 2016   2     49
123037  INFO         9 0002 2017   1   NULL
123010  COMP         9 0007 2016   1     82
123010  ISYS         9 0026 2015   2     82
123011  ISYS         9 0026 2015   2     88
123012  ISYS         9 0026 2015   2     66
123010  COMP         9 0038 2016   2     77
123010  COMP         9 0041 2016   1     45
123010  COMP         9 0041 2017   1   NULL
123010  ISYS         9 0049 2016   1     88
```

So student 101 has a repeated subject 000002

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  Is this a homework problem?

Comment: group by, having, count...

Comment: There's no 000002 in the dataset.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 0):

Use GROUP BY and HAVING function :

```
  SELECT student,subject 
  FROM your_table 
  GROUP BY student,subject 
  HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
select Student,subject from table group by student, subject having count(*)>1
```